# <BS> and <C-w> delete entire line in (terminal mode from a command) instead of a single character

Tags: neovim, terminal-buffer

I'm creating a mapping which is supposed to navigate to a specific window (call `TEST_WIN`), focus in on the terminal and then delete a single character.

The goal of this command is to navigate to the terminal buffer and execute the last line that was executed, but to remove the last word of the command which will be an argument `-d` or `-rd`.

The mapping looks like this:

```
noremap ';  :let curWin = win_getid()<CR>:call win_gotoid(TEST_WIN)<CR>A<C-c><C-l><up><BS>
```

I have substituted `<BS>` in with `<C-w>` and both of these delete the entire line instead of a single charater/word.

How can I get it to just delete a single word or character?

I should add that when I am controlling the terminal without the command, `<C-w>` and the backspace key on my Mac both work as expected. The problem only arises during the command.

Comment: I'm having trouble with some of this. What does "I have substituted in with and both  of these..." mean? "In with"? Also, you need to separate different commands with `|` (`\|` in mappings). And what is the `A` at the end supposed to do? Please provide full and accurate details. Thanks.

Comment: Well, by formatting the code I answered some of my questions. :)

Comment: @BLayer edited with command explanation.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems the OP is using bash, here's a non-mapping, non-vim solution that should work in the shell:

```sh
!!:-
```

From `man bash`:

```
       !!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'.
[…]
       x-y    A range of words; `-y' abbreviates `0-y'.
[…]
       x-     Abbreviates x-$ like x*, but omits the last word.
```

I think you can even omit the colon, since the word-designator starts with `-`.

---

This also has far less "special characters" like <kbd>Up</kbd> that need to be handled specially in vim, though see filbranden's answer for how to send the sequence to a `:terminal`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know this before. Incredible. Thanks so much.

Comment: @libby `man bash` and search for the `history expansion` header

Comment: Save a keystroke: `!!-`.

Comment: I did mention omitting the colon @BLayer but youre correct

Comment: Sorry. Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Previously answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620416/281844).

Terminal windows are special, you can't just have a mapping use a command to switch to insert mode and then include characters to type in the terminal directly.

Instead, you should call function [`term_sendkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#term_sendkeys%28%29) to interact with the terminal.

Something like the following should work:

```
function! TermHistory()
  call win_gotoid(TEST_WIN)
  call term_sendkeys('', "\<C-c>\<C-l>\<Up>\<BS>")
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> '; :call TermHistory()<CR>
```

**UPDATE:** NeoVim doesn't have `term_sendkeys()` available, so on NeoVim you need `feedkeys()`. For the keys from `feedkeys()` to go to the program running in the terminal, you also need `startinsert`.

This function definition seems to work in NeoVim:

```
function! TermHistory()
  call win_gotoid(TEST_WIN)
  startinsert
  call feedkeys("\<C-c>\<C-l>\<Up>\<BS>")
endfunction
```

Comment: when I do that it's giving me some really weird output.
If I open up my buffer and run `echo Hello World`, then I get out of the terminal and navigate over it and run `call chansend(b:terminal_job_id, "\<C-c>\<C-l>\<up>\<BS>\<CR>")
` 
  
I get:  
  
`bash-3.2$ �ku�kb`   
`bash: �ku�kb: command not found`  
`bash-3.2$`

Comment: it doesn't like the "\<BS>" we're sending it

Comment: And `"\<Up>"`, that's what the `?ku` is... Looks like `chansend()` sends it in a different way than expected... I really don't know the right answer to this one. Let's see if someone else can come up with something better. If I have some time, I may take a look at it, I can probably find a NeoVim somewhere (I'm usually a Vim user myself.)

Comment: I'm just as happy with a solution that saves the last terminal command to a variable, removes the last word and then sends it back into the terminal (without backspace and up)

Comment: It seems `feedkeys()` works. I updated my answer now.